# Textarea Scorllbar: How can I move the thumb?

Tags: html, css

How can I move the thumb to the left where there is an available space?

[image]

I tried adding margins and paddings, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I tried adding position: absolute; to the thumb in attempt to pop it out and adjust the position, but still it does not work. Is there a certain property which I can use to move the scrollbar? Or should I do some techniques/tricks to it because  YouTube does not provide any information about it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Workshop</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font: Noto Sans Tai Lue (400, 500, 600, 700) -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+New+Tai+Lue:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center position-absolute" id="contactUsForm">
        <!-- Image Start -->
        <div class="col-6">
            
        </div>
        <!-- Image End -->

        <!-- Form Start -->
        <form class="col-6 p-5">
            <!-- Name Start -->
            <input class="pt-2 pb-2 pl-4 pr-4 rounded-pill font-weight-bold" type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            <!-- Name End -->

            <!-- Email Start -->
            <input class="pt-2 pb-2 pl-4 pr-4 mt-3 rounded-pill font-weight-bold" type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Email">
            <!-- Email End -->

            <!-- Message Start -->
            <textarea class="p-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold" rows="7" placeholder="Message">textspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspamtextspam</textarea>
            <!-- Message End -->
        </form>
        <!-- Form End -->
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    background-color: #7765c8;
}

#contactUsForm {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans New Tai Lue', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#contactUsForm input, #contactUsForm textarea  {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#contactUsForm input {
    height: 50px;
}

#contactUsForm textarea {
    border-radius: 25px;
    resize: none;
}

#contactUsForm textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;;
}

#contactUsForm textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
```

Comment: Are you tying to position the scrollbar from right to left?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect, you can use the `background-clip` property in conjunction with a transparent `border` for `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`. And to maintain the necessary rounding, use an `border-radius` in the form of an ellipse:

```css
#contactUsForm textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 30px;
}

#contactUsForm textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px / 10px;
    background-color: #757575;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```